# Computing the eigenvector from a linearly independent system of equations

Tags: linear-algebra, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

I am trying to compute the eigenvector associated to $\lambda_{1}=i$, which (for my matrix) means I have to solve the system of four equations:

$$\begin{cases}(\xi-i)x-y=0 \\ x+(\xi-i)y=0 \\ (\xi-i)z-w=0 \\ 4z+(\xi-i)w=0\end{cases}$$

$\implies \begin{cases}x=-y \\4z=-w\end{cases}$

But these two equations are linearly independent, so how do I write my eigenvector?

Comment: You can write your eigenvector as: $(x,-x,z,-4z)^T$, where $x,z$ can take any value in $\mathbb R$, as long as your eigenvector is not zero!

Comment: Let $x$ be any complex number and $z$ be any complex number (not both zero).  Plug those into the vector in ^thanasissdr's answer and that'll be one of your eigenvectors.  The thing to see here, though, is that your eigenspace is $2$-dimensional.  Thus you really need to find $2$ linearly independent eigenvectors.

Comment: @Bye_World And how do I find the two linearly independent eigenvectors?

Comment: If you choose any two sets of numbers $x$ and $z$, chances are you'll get linearly independent vectors.  But for a couple of easy ones, just notice that $(1,-1,0,0)^T$ and $(0,0,1,-4)^T$ are linearly independent.

Answer (score 0):

Considering your last set of equations, the rank of matrix corresponding to your homogeneous system of 4 variables is 2 thereby giving 4-2=2 linearly independent non-zero eigenvectors.

The two eigenvectors are of type [a -a 0 0] and [0 0 -b 4b] where a ,b∈C